# How to print lines with specific strings in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to print the lines with a speciic string in a line. For instance, In a text file if the file has 'There are 5 lines in a text file' then it should search for 'In line1,', 'In line3', 'In line5'
and print all these lines.

```
There are 5 lines in a text file
In line1,
In line2,
In line3,
In line4,
In line5,
```

expected output

```
There are 5 lines in a text file, In line1, In line3, In line5,
```

So far, I can print a line with a specific string.

```
with open ('input.txt', 'r') as f:
     for line in :
        if 'There are 5 lines in a text' in line:
            print (line)
```

With this, I can print only the first line. How do we print all these lines together using python? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the code what you have tried so far?

Comment: Is it alway five lines or can it be changed ?

Comment: @ThilinaLakshan It will change. It is just a part of the file that I am trying to print. It should search 'There are 5 lines in a text file' if it exists then it should search for lines.

Comment: Is the line `'There are 5 lines in a text'` always the first line or can it be at random line number in the file?

Comment: @JoeFerndz It can be random. It is just a part of a file.

Comment: Why you state the expected line with all strings but wrote that you only need a specific string?

Comment: @M.Innat Here, 'and print all these lines.' means to print the lines of specific strings 'There are 5 lines in a text file' then it should search for 'In line1,' in a line, 'In line3,' in a line, 'In line5,' in line and print these

Comment: Looks like you want to locate the line `There are 5 lines in a text` first. Then in the subsequent lines, you want to search for the substring `In line1` or  `In line3` or `In line5`  and if found, you want to print the line. Correct?

Comment: @JoeFerndz Exactly

Comment: For that, it's better to use JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have understood the problem statement, here's the code to do it.

```
found = False
in_line = ['In line1', 'In line3', 'In line5'] 
with open ('abc.txt', 'r') as f:
     for line in f:
        if 'There are 5 lines in a text' in line:
            print (line.strip())
            found = True
        if found and any(x in line for x in in_line):
            print (line.strip())
```

If the source file is :

```
There are 5 lines in a text file
In line1,
In line2,
In line3,
In line4,
In line5,
```

Then the output will be:

```
There are 5 lines in a text file
In line1,
In line3,
In line5,
```

If the source file is:

```
In line1,
In line2,
In line3,
There are 5 lines in a text file
In line4,
In line5,
```

Then the output will be:

```
There are 5 lines in a text file
In line5,
```

I would recommend that you update the question with all the information you shared in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract number from the sentence,

```py
import re


# If txt match with specific format it extract the value from the sentence and return it
# otherwise return 0
def readDefinition(txt):
    match = re.search("^There are (\d+) lines in a text file$", txt)
    if match:
        return int(match.group(1))
    return 0

with open("input.txt") as file:
    lines = file.read().split('\n')
    
    i = 0
    while len(lines) > i:
        count = readDefinition(lines[i]) # try to match and extract value
        if count > 0:
            print(lines[i], ":", *lines[i+1 : i+count+1]) # print result
            i += count + 1
        else:
            i += 1
```

If you are looking for **searching** over sub sequent string,
You can search inside `lines[i+1 : i+count+1]`

For example, if your `input.txt` looks like this,

```
There are 5 lines in a text file
In line1,
In line2,
In line3,
In line4,
In line5,
extra

There are 3 lines in a text file
In line1,
In line2,
In line3,
extra
extra
```

Output will be,

```
There are 5 lines in a text file : In line1, In line2, In line3, In line4, In line5,
There are 3 lines in a text file : In line1, In line2, In line3,
```